# HDFS File Compaction with continuous ingestion

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

We have few tables in HDFS which are getting approx. 40k new files per day. We need to compact these tables every two weeks and for that we need to stop ingestion.

We have spark ingestion getting data from kafka and adding to HDFS (Hive external tables) every 30 mins. The data is queried as soon as it is ingested, our SLA is less than an hour so we can not increase the batch interval.

The tables are partition on two fields, we get older data constantly so most of the partitions are updated during each injection batch

eg:
/user/head/warehouse/main_table/state=CA/store=macys/part-00000-017258f8-aaa-bbb-ccc-wefdsds.c000.snappy.parquet

We are looking into ways to reduce number of file creations but even with that we will have to do compaction every 3/4 weeks if not two.

As most of the partitions are updated constantly, we need to stop the injection (~ 1 day) before starting compaction which is impacting our users.

I am looking for ways to compact automatically with out stopping the ingestion?

Answer (score 0):

The chosen partitioning scheme is somewhat unfortunate. Still there are a couple of things you can do. I'm relying on the fact that you can change partition's location atomically in Hive (alter table ... partition ... set location):

1. Copy a partition's hdfs directory to a different location
2. Compact copied data
3. Copy new files that were ingested since step 1
4. do "alter table ... partition ... set location" to point Hive to a new compacted location.
5. Start ingesting to this new location (in case if this step is tricky you can just as well replace the "small" files in the original partition location with their compacted version and do "alter table ... partition ... set location" again to point Hive back to the original partition location.

You'll have to keep this process running iterating partition-by-partition on a continuous basis.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Facha for your suggestions, really appreciate it.

I am pretty new to HDFS concept so please dont mind basic questions,

What would be the impact on running queries which are accessing these specific files while doing swapping of uncompacted files with compacted files (alter table ... partition ... set location). I believe that the queries might fail. Who can we minimize the impact?

Copy a partition's hdfs directory to a different location

> > As we have two partitions in one table, state and store, will I have to iterate through each sub partition?

/tableName/state=CA/store=macys/file1.parquet
/tableName/state=CA/store=macys/file2.parquet

/tableName/state=CA/store=JCP/file2.parquet
/tableName/state=CA/store=JCP/file2.parquet

/tableName/state=NY/store=macys/file1.parquet
/tableName/state=NY/store=macys/file2.parquet

/tableName/state=NY/store=JCP/file2.parquet
/tableName/state=NY/store=JCP/file2.parquet

```
For each state
    for each store
        get list of files in this dir to replace later
        compact 
            /tableName/state=$STATE/store=$STORE (SPARK JOb?)
        replace uncompacted files with compacted files
        alter table ... partition ... set location
```

I would prefer your other suggestion in step 5 " just as well replace the "small" files in the original partition location with their compacted version"

How would I go ahead with implementing it, will it be best done with scripting or scala or some other programing language. I have basic knowledge of scripting, good experiencs in java and new to scala but can learn in couple of days.

Regards,
P